# Localstack set signed url endpoints returned

Tags: localstack

We were evaluating if there is a way to have localstack return the URLs based off a preset environment var vs the network host interface its contacted over.  The docker-compose resolvable network name is localstack:4566 but upon obtaining signed urls I would prefer them to be localhost:4566 as our local client testing (react) is not going to be able to resolve localstack:4566...

```
LOCALSTACK_HOST localhost.localstack.cloud:4566 (default)   This is interpolated into URLs and addresses that are returned by LocalStack. It has the form <hostname>:<port>.
```

This variable looked promising but sure doesn't appear to work as intended.

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  localstack:    
    image: localstack/localstack:2.1.0
    ports:
      - 4566:4566            # LocalStack Gateway
      - 4510-4559:4510-4559  # external services port range
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=1
      - LOCALSTACK_HOST=localhost:4566
    networks:
      - devnet
    volumes:
      - localstack:/var/lib/localstack
      - ./scripts/localstack/ready.d:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d
```

When we contact localstack over devnet we received the urls back as shown below:

```
http://localstack:4566/dev-upload-bucket/uploads/e9530040-5bac-48b4-8768-2aff1919e483/hello?partNumber=1&uploadId=eDOCkjtyyQw4dCH8GhgG0wSlVA12ZOAwXxXE4Iqn75WGl844NJgJZNg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYA3ELKN4FI62BMFI%2F20230725%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230725T211351Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzENn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F...
```

Comment: This seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767975/docker-compose-how-to-access-localstack-resources-both-from-container-and-host ... adds a complex wrinkle for signed urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating pre-signed URL is purely a client-side operation done by the CLI or your SDK (it does not send a request to LocalStack or AWS). It will use the configured credentials to pre-signed a request only, using the configured endpoint.

The endpoint returned when generating pre-signed URL will be the one you're setting when creating your S3 client. So you can create an S3 client only to generate your pre-signed URL, it won't need to contact LocalStack, and no configuration can be done on LocalStack side.

Comment: Indeed.  You are correct and I just read the algorithm itself last week.  Been chasing ghosts here for a good hour.   Initializing the dev environment with localhost:4546 as the client will "break" other items though like SQS which the internals of the app are using.  I'll have to evaluate this a bit to determine a good way to accomodate this for dev environments for this particular use case with UI integration.

Comment: Could you maybe only initialize an S3 client to create those pre-signed URL in your dev environment, that would do nothing else? Maybe your other clients could keep the same configuration as now with `localstack:4566`, but having a special S3 client for these URL could help.